# Trouble Using Template Bubblesort with Array of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, struct

So my goal is to read in some data and sort it by population, but I have to use a sort that can accept multiple data types. I was instructed to use a template to do this, but every time I pass the array "results[i].pop" to my bubblesort function I receive the error

> no matching function for call to ‘bubblesort(std::string&)’
>    bubblesort(results[i].pop);"
>    note: candidate is:
>   election.cpp:32:3: note: template T bubblesort(T*)
>    T bubblesort(T ar[])
>      ^
>   election.cpp:32:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> election.cpp:106:34: note:   cannot convert ‘results[i].election::pop’ (type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’) to type ‘std::basic_string*’
>    bubblesort(results[i].pop);

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; 

struct election {

string party;
string state;
string pop;
string reps;
int ratio;
};


template <typename T>
void bubblesort(T ar[])
{

//Bubblesort
int n = 51;
int swaps = 1;
    while(swaps)
    {
    swaps = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                    if (ar[i] > ar[i + 1])
                    {
                            swap(ar[i],ar[i+1]);
                            swaps = 1;
                    }
            }
    }
//End Bubblesort

}


void delete_chars(string & st, string ch)
{
    int i = st.find(ch);
    while (i > -1)
    {
            st.replace(i,1,"");
            i = st.find(ch);
    }
}



int main()
{
int i = 0;
int n = 51;
election results[n];

int population[n];
int electoralVotes[n];
int ratio[n];
string st;
fstream inData;

//Read in Data from Text File
inData.open("electionresults.txt");



//Print Array as is
cout << "Array Printed As is" << endl;
cout << left << setw(10) << "Party" << setw(20) << "State" << setw(20) <<     "Population" << setw(15) << "Representatives" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    getline(inData,st);
    results[i].party = st.substr(0,1);
    results[i].state = st.substr(8,14);
    results[i].pop = st.substr(24,10);
    results[i].reps = st.substr(40,2);
    cout << left << setw(10) << results[i].party << setw(20) <<     results[i].state << setw(20) << results[i].pop << setw(15) << results[i].reps << endl;
}

 //Array Sorted by Population
cout << "Array Sorted By Population" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << left << setw(10) << "Party" << setw(20) << "State" << setw(20) <<              "Population" << setw(15) << "Representatives" << endl;



for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
bubblesort<string>(results[i].pop);
}
```

Comment: Your template function is declaring as returning `T`. There is no `return` statment in the template function that returns `T`. Furthermore, there's no reason, whatsoever, for a bubblesort function to return anything. Furthermore, your bubblesort function takes an array as a parameter. When your `main()` calls it, `main()` does not pass the array as a parameter, but something else. The entire code is completely wrong. You need to spend more time studying templates. There are too many problems here.

Comment: Well this is my first time using templates so yea. I changed the function to void instead of T but I still get the same error.

Comment: That was just one problem, out of many.

Comment: Your template function requires an array of `T`.  You are passing `pop`, and that isn't an array.  If you want to see how to put together a sort template function, why not see how it's actually done by looking at the `std::sort` interface?  You forgot to templatize the sort *criteria* -- instead you hardcoded the comparison with no room for customization.

Answer (score 0):

For your bubblesort to work, you need to implement the greater than operator(>) for the election struct:

```
struct election 
{

    string party;
    string state;
    string pop;
    string reps;
    int ratio;
    bool operator>( election a)
    {
        return pop > a.pop;
    }
};
```

Now call the bubblesort by passing the results array:

```
bubblesort<election>(results);
```

A side note your function should pass in the size rather than hardcoding the size in the function(`void bubblesort(T ar[], int size)`).  This gives your function much more functionality and adaptability.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It's refreshing to have actual help rather than be ridiculed because I'm still new at this.

Comment: @Nar1y Why did you bring up being ridiculed?  Also, what if you need to sort on any of the other fields?  You can't do that since multiple `operator >`'s are not possible.  My comment in the main part of the thread addressed this.

Comment: @Nar1y -- I took the time to provide an answer and hopefully an explanation on how to solve the issue in a more generic way.  Please check this out, as it gives a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer addressed the issue if you only wanted to sort on `pop`.  However, it is a limited solution, and won't address the real issue of sorting on any field (today it's "pop", but what if this isn't the case tomorrow, where you want to sort on "ratio"?).  The issue is that you cannot provide more than one `operator >` to do this and you're basically stuck only sorting on `pop`.

Another solution is to provide the `bubblesort` function with an additional template parameter that defines what to do when given two `T`'s, whether one `T` should be placed before the other `T` in the sorted array.

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
//...
template <typename T, typename cmp>
void bubblesort(T ar[], int n, cmp compare_fn)
{
    int swaps = 1;
    while (swaps)
    {
        swaps = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!compare_fn(ar[i], ar[i + 1]))
            {
                std::swap(ar[i], ar[i + 1]);
                swaps = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

// keep our original 2 param bubble sort, but let it call the one above
template <typename T>
void bubblesort(T ar[], int n)
{
    // call general version using <
    bubblesort(ar, n, std::less<T>());
}
```

We basically have two functions, where the two parameter bubblesort function calls the general 3 parameter `bubblesort` version that takes a third parameter, which describes the comparison.

The two parameter version of `bubblesort` is used when you want to call `bubblesort` for the "simple" cases, where your items are

1. In an array and
2. You can compare `T` using `<` and
3. You want to sort in ascending order (which is why we used `<` and not `>` for the general case).

For example, an array of `int` needs to be sorted, and you simply want to sort it in ascending order:

```
int someArray[10];
//...
bubblesort<int>(someArray, 10);  // sort ascending
```

However, we don't want to do a "simple" sort on int, or even `std::string`.  We want to sort on `election`, and not only that, on `election.pop`.

If you look at the first `bubblesort` function above, note that we replaced the comparison using `>` with a call to a function `compare_fn`.  Note that the parameter is defaulted to the [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) function object.  This is why the second `bubblesort` function works for simple types, since `std::less` uses `<` to compare.

However, if you tried to call the `bubblesort` using only two parameters using `election`, you come across another compiler error, basically stating that `election` has no `operator <` to compare with.  The solution to that is either

1) to provide such an operator < (similar to the other answer given) to the `election` struct or

2) Write a custom comparison function.

So let's go over each of these solutions.

---

**Solution 1:**

If we use 1), the `election` struct will look like this:

```
struct election
{
    std::string party;
    std::string state;
    std::string pop;
    std::string reps;
    int ratio;
    bool operator <(const election& e) const { return pop < e.pop; }
};

int main()
{
   //...
   bubblesort<election>(results, n);
}
```

This will now sort on `results` using `pop` as the item to sort on due to the `operator <` defined in `election` being used by `std::less<>`.

[Here is an example using overloaded < in `election`](http://ideone.com/xqscWD)

However, this solution has the same issues as the other answer, in that you can only define one `operator <` that takes a `const election&` as a parameter.  If you wanted to sort on `ratio`, for example, you're out of luck, or if you want to sort `pop` in descending order, you're out of luck.  This is where option 2) above will be used.

---

**Solution 2:**

We can define what we want to sort on, the sort order, etc. by providing a custom comparison function, function object, or [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that returns `true` if the first `T` should come before the second `T` that's passed into the comparison function, `false` otherwise.

Let's try a function:

```
bool compare_pop(const election& e1, const election& e2)
{
   return e1.pop < e2.pop;  // if e1.pop comes before e2.pop, return true, else false
}

int main()
{
   //...
   bubblesort<election>(results, n, compare_pop);
}
```

What will happen now is that this will call the first version of `bubblesort` that takes a comparison function as a parameter.  The `bubblesort` template function will now call `compare_pop` to determine if the items are out of order.  If `compare_pop` returns `false` the `bubblesort` function will swap the items, otherwise it will leave them alone.

[Here is a live example with an array of 3 elections, sorted on pop](http://ideone.com/LG4fN3)

If you wanted to use a lambda function instead of writing another compare function, that will work too:

```
int main()
{
   //...
   bubblesort<election>(results, n, [&](const element& e1, const element& e2) { return e1.pop < e2.pop; });
}
```

The above will do the same thing as the function example, except that you no longer need to write a separate function as the lambda syntax is used as the function.

[Example using lambda syntax](http://ideone.com/Tuxcdf)

---

So now, what if we want to sort on `pop`, but descending and not ascending?  Simple -- call `bubblesort` with a different function or lambda:

```
bool compare_pop_up(const election& e1, const election& e2)
{
   return e1.pop > e2.pop;  // if e1.pop comes after e2.pop, return true, else false
}

int main()
{
   //...
   bubblesort<election>(results, n, compare_pop_up);
}
```

or using lambda:

```
int main()
{
   //...
   bubblesort<election>(results, n, 
                 [&](const element&e1, const element& e2) 
                 { return e1.pop > e2.pop;});
}
```

and magically, the `bubblesort` does the job, sorting on `pop` in descending order.

[Here is a live example with an array of 3 elections, sorted on pop, descending](http://ideone.com/zywNcr)

What if you want to sort on `ratio`?  Same thing -- provide a different function or lambda:

```
bool compare_ratio(const election& e1, const election& e2)
{
   return e1.ratio < e2.ratio;  
}

int main()
{
   //...
   bubblesort<election>(results, n, compare_ratio);
}
```

or using lambda:

```
int main()
{
   //...
   bubblesort<election>(results, n, 
                 [&](const element&e1, const element& e2) 
                 { return e1.ratio < e2.ratio;});
}
```

This will sort on `ratio` in ascending order of the `ratio`.

---

The other issue with your code is that you are using non-standard C++ syntax in defining your arrays.  You're doing this:

```
election results[n];
```

This is not standard C++ syntax, as C++ only allows arrays to be created using a compile-time expression to denote the number of items.  You're using something called `Variable Length Arrays`, which is **not** standard.

Instead, you can use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which is standard C++.

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<election> results(n);
//...
bubblesort<election>(results.data(), results.size(), compare_pop)
```